# Using Map in a function definition

Tags: list-manipulation, functions

I want to calculate the hessian of a matrix. So each element gets replaced by a 2 by 2 matrix.

```
hessian[im_, s_] := 
  {{gD[im, 2, 0, 2], gD[im, 1, 1, 2]}, {gD[im, 1, 1, 2], gD[im, 0, 2, 2]}};
```

Now `im = My matrix`.

I want to modify my hessian function in some way (using `Map`) such that when I calculate the hessian of `im`, 1 element at a time is calculated by `gD`. At this time `gD` works on the entire `im` matrix.

How do I do this? Any help (preferable code) will be very helpful. I am new to *Mathematica*, struggling, and very frustrated.

Comment: More details on the definition of `gD` or a simple example with data might be helpful. Also [this implementation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Hessian.html) may help you. Or are you just looking for something like `hessian[im_, s_] := 
  {{gD[#, 2, 0, 2], gD[#, 1, 1, 2]}, {gD[#, 1, 1, 2], gD[#, 0, 2, 2]}}&/@im;`

Answer (score 2):

This might be what you're after (although some more details would indeed help):

```
hessian[im_] := Map[
  {
    {gD[#, 2, 0, 2], gD[#, 1, 1, 2]},
    {gD[#, 1, 1, 2], gD[#, 0, 2, 2]}
  } &,
  im,
  {2}
];
```

This is almost Karsten's suggestion, the difference being the third argument to [`Map`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html), `{2}`. It tells `Map` to only map on elements at level 2 of the input expression.
Here it is in action on a generic 2x2 matrix:

```
hessian[ Array[m, {2, 2}] ] // MatrixForm
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]